# Social sharing buttons missing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, sharing

Am I missing something, or have the social buttons under the vote counter disappeared (network-wide)?

[image: Missing social buttons]

I must say, I know that a lot of folks (especially on SO) found the visual noise obnoxious, but I used them with some regularity.

Previously:
[image: Social sharing]

Answer (score 3):

They [were removed last week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80910/166936). They apparently saw "abysmal" usage rates and Kevin Montrose had been itching to remove them. I specifically mentioned that sites like UX likely use the sharing buttons a lot more than Stack Overflow (I was afraid SO likely heavily biases their opinion on the matter) but he said their usage was mostly the same across the network, and that while UX had more sharing than most it wasn't enough to keep the buttons around.

Remember you can share any post (question or answer) with the aptly titled `link` link at the bottom of the post:

> [image]

Note links shared from that URL count toward the Announcer/ect badge.

I've [suggested the buttons be moved into the `link` link under each post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/add-social-media-sharing-icons-to-the-link-popup/136771#136771) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm still not sure of the benefit to removing them. Really, was page load speed seriously a problem with those options? And it's not as if there is anything else that watch itching to take the place of those buttons either. Although I don't want to just stuff elements into the page just because there is room (white space = good and all that) those sharing options had a useful function on this site. Now I have to copy, paste *and* have to think of what to write in my sharing tweets now!

Comment: @JonW people said the share your answer thing was annoying (it was in full bold and appeared in an awkward flash when you posted your answer). No idea why it was necessary to remove the sharing buttons other than some grouchy anti-sharing people.

Comment: No surprise here, I'm sure: Woo hoo for a cleaner look!! Though I never used them, I think it would be nice to have the previous share functionality baked into the "link" dialog for those that did.

Comment: @Karen that's actually exactly what I've suggested here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/add-social-media-sharing-icons-to-the-link-popup/136771#136771

Comment: @BenBrocka Great minds!  I joined SO just to give you a +1 :)

Comment: I think we need to at least ask for them back... it is really bugging me not being able to share posts with one click.

Comment: @LisaTweedie you could either vote up the question/answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/add-social-media-sharing-icons-to-the-link-popup/136771#136771 or make a formal request on Meta Stack Overflow too, that's where the cross-network feature requests go

Comment: Hey, let's design some counter-intuitive buttons in an odd place and then complain that they don't get used! That makes sense!

Comment: @Rahul and then make them annoying to prove that users don't like them, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Now this is offically implemented: [Add social media sharing icons to the “link” popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140905/166936).

Click the Share link below and post to share it; question or answer!

Answer (score 2):

There's now a userscript to impliment my suggestion:
 [Add Share buttons to the “link” box](https://stackapps.com/questions/3514/add-share-buttons-to-the-link-box). Chrome/Firefox users can put this to use until SE changes something with sharing (if they do).